# Get last output of dynamic_rnn in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using dynamic_rnn to process MNIST data:

```
# LSTM Cell
lstm = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=200,
                         forget_bias=1.0,
                         initializer=tf.random_normal)

# Initial state
istate = lstm.zero_state(batch_size, "float")

# Get lstm cell output
output, states = rnn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, X, initial_state=istate)

# Output at last time point T
output_at_T = output[:, 27, :]
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/bhf9MgMe

The input to the lstm is `(batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)`

As a result the dimensions of `output_at_T` is `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_units)` where `num_units=200`.

I need to get the last output along the `sequence_length`  dimension. In the code above, this is hardcoded as `27`. However, I do not know the `sequence_length` in advance as it can change from batch to batch in my application.

I tried:

```
output_at_T = output[:, -1, :]
```

but it says negative indexing is not implemented yet, and I tried using a placeholder variable as well as a constant (into which I could ideally feed the `sequence_length` for a particular batch); neither worked.

Any way to implement something like this in tensorflow atm?

Comment: Are your sequence of equal length?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last output of a dynamic\_rnn in TensorFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-the-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 13):

Have you noticed that there are two outputs from dynamic_rnn?

1. Output 1, let's call it h, has all outputs at each time steps (i.e. h_1, h_2, etc),
2. Output 2, final_state, has two elements: the cell_state, and the last output for each element of the batch (as long as you input the sequence length to dynamic_rnn).

So from:

```
h, final_state= tf.dynamic_rnn( ..., sequence_length=[batch_size_vector], ... )
```

the last state for each element in the batch is:

```
final_state.h
```

Note that this includes the case when the length of the sequence is different for each element of the batch, as we are using the sequence_length argument.

Comment: Does `final_state.h` return the last *output* or the last *hidden state*?

Comment: @bluesummers final_state.h is the final activation for each element in the batch (i.e. final output) and final_state.c the state of the cell

Comment: thanks. Just to be clear, `final_state.h` will have the dimensions of [batch_size, lstm_units] ?

Answer (score 5):

This is what [gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) is for!

```
def extract_axis_1(data, ind):
    """
    Get specified elements along the first axis of tensor.
    :param data: Tensorflow tensor that will be subsetted.
    :param ind: Indices to take (one for each element along axis 0 of data).
    :return: Subsetted tensor.
    """

    batch_range = tf.range(tf.shape(data)[0])
    indices = tf.stack([batch_range, ind], axis=1)
    res = tf.gather_nd(data, indices)

    return res
```

In your case (assuming `sequence_length` is a 1-D tensor with the length of each axis 0 element):

```
output = extract_axis_1(output, sequence_length - 1)
```

Now output is a tensor of dimension `[batch_size, num_cells]`.

Comment: There is no need to do this, dynamic_rnn has as an output the last state. Check my answer.

Comment: @Escachator That only works if the sequences are of the same length (inside a batch). OP says "I do not know the `sequence_length` in advance as it can change from batch to batch in my application" so that may be a fair assumption - I don't know. My answer works even if sequences are of different length inside the batch (and the data is padded).

Comment: if you know (or get) 'ind' you know the sequence length for each element of your batch. Then you can input that in the 'sequence_length' parameter of dynamic_rnn and it will stop calculating once it arrives there on each element of the batch. Then you just take the final_state.h. I possibly should add that to my answer.

Comment: @Escachator That is true but it doesn't really help if you want to access those last elements! See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-the-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow).

Comment: you can always develop a function that, given a batch, gives you the sequence length of each element. I assume you are padding it. You can do that even using the new tf.data.Dataset API with the map function. Then you input that in the sequence_length on the tf.dynamic_rnn and you are done. It could be even faster, as dynamic_rnn will stop calculating on each element once it arrives to the end of it.

Comment: @Escachator Think you are misunderstanding some things... Breaking them into separate comments for ease of viewing.

Comment: @Escachator
1. We are talking about getting a symbolic representation of the outputs which may occur at different timesteps inside the batch. `sequence_length` does not help with that. See [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-the-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow) I previously posted and try out the example in the question for yourself. `sequence_length` will just zero out outputs beyond the given lengths.

Comment: @Escachator
2. [The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) say that `sequence_length` is used "to copy-through state and zero-out outputs" and therefore is "more for correctness than performance". So I don't see evidence to the claim that "dynamic_rnn will stop calculating on each element once it arrives to the end of it." Let me know if you have different info since that would be pretty cool! I'm guessing that because tensorflow is built to be run on highly parallelizable hardware that what's written in the docs is actually true in code.

Comment: I see the value of your answer, I actually used it for some time. However the question is about taking the last activation of each element for each batch, where each element has an arbitrary size. The question is not to take some arbitrary element of the activation vector. Hence the simplest way is to use sequence_length and take final_state.h

Answer (score 3):

```
output[:, -1, :]
```

works with Tensorflow 1.x now!!

Comment: This only works if the `sequence_length` is the same for each element in the `output`.

Comment: the question is specifically about dynamic lengths, for which this does not work

Answer (score 2):

Most answers cover it thoroughly, but this code snip might help understand what's really being returned by the `dynamic_rnn` layer

=> Tuple of **(outputs, final_output_state)**.

So for an input with *max sequence length*  of T time steps *outputs* is of the shape `[Batch_size, T, num_inputs]` (given `time_major`=False; default value) and it contains the output state at each timestep `h1, h2.....hT`.

And *final_output_state* is of the shape `[Batch_size,num_inputs]` and has the final cell state `cT` and output state `hT` of each batch sequence.

But since the `dynamic_rnn` is being used my guess is your sequence lengths vary for each batch.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    # Create input data
    X = np.random.randn(2, 10, 8)

    # The second example is of length 6 
    X[1,6:] = 0
    X_lengths = [10, 6]

    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)

    outputs, states  = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,
                                         dtype=tf.float64,
                                         sequence_length=X_lengths,
                                         inputs=X)

    result = tf.contrib.learn.run_n({"outputs": outputs, "states":states},
                                    n=1,
                                    feed_dict=None)
    assert result[0]["outputs"].shape == (2, 10, 64)
    print result[0]["outputs"].shape
    print result[0]["states"].h.shape
    # the final outputs state and states returned must be equal for each      
    # sequence
    assert(result[0]["outputs"][0][-1]==result[0]["states"].h[0]).all()
    assert(result[0]["outputs"][-1][5]==result[0]["states"].h[-1]).all()
    assert(result[0]["outputs"][-1][-1]==result[0]["states"].h[-1]).all()
```

The final assertion will fail as the final state for the 2nd sequence is at 6th time step ie. the index 5 and the rest of the outputs from [6:9] are all 0s in the 2nd timestep

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Stackoverflow and cannot comment yet so I am writing this new answer. @VM_AI, the last index is `tf.shape(output)[1] - 1`. 
So, reusing your answer:

```
# Let's first fetch the last index of seq length
# last_index would have a scalar value
last_index = tf.shape(output)[1] - 1
# Then let's reshape the output to [sequence_length,batch_size,num_units]
# for convenience
output_rs = tf.transpose(output,[1,0,2])
# Last state of all batches
last_state = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(output_rs,last_index)
```

This works for me.

Comment: the question asks for the last dynamic state, not the last state in the array

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the shape of your `output` tensor using `tf.shape(output)`. The `tf.shape()` function will return a 1d tensor containing the sizes of the `output` tensor. In your example, this would be `(batch_size, sequence_length, num_units)`

You should then be able to extract the value of `output_at_T` as `output[:, tf.shape(output)[1], :]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in TensorFlow `tf.shape` that allows you to get the symbolic interpretation of shape rather than `None` being returned by `output._shape[1]`. And after fetching the last index you can lookup by using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, which is recommended especially when the data to be fetched is high as this does parallel lookup `32 by default`.

```
# Let's first fetch the last index of seq length
# last_index would have a scalar value
last_index = tf.shape(output)[1] 
# Then let's reshape the output to [sequence_length,batch_size,num_units]
# for convenience
output_rs = tf.transpose(output,[1,0,2])
# Last state of all batches
last_state = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(output_rs,last_index)
```

This should work.

Just to clarify what @Benoit Steiner said. His solution would not work as tf.shape would return symbolic interpretation of the shape value, and such cannot be used for slicing tensors i.e., direct indexing