# Get the last output of a dynamic_rnn in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have a 3-D tensor of shape `[batch, None, dim]` where the second dimension, i.e. the timesteps, is unknown. I use `dynamic_rnn` to process such input, like in the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)
```

Actually, running this snipped with some actual numbers, I have some reasonable results:

```
inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                    [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                    dtype=np.int32)
lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_ = sess.run(output, {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print(output_)
```

And the output is:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.02188676 -0.01294564  0.05340237 -0.47148666]
  [ 0.0343586  -0.02243731  0.0870839  -0.89869428]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.00284752 -0.00315077  0.00108094 -0.99883419]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]
```

Is there a way to get a 3-D tensor of shape `[batch, 1, hidden]` with the *last relevant output* of the dynamic RNN? Thanks!

Comment: I like your code style!  This is a great question for learning how nn's work too. thanks

Comment: The accepted answer is not the preferred way to do it. Please look at @ShaoTang's answer at the end.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for pointing out. Anyway, it looks like ShaoTang is pointing to states, while the question is specifically on outputs. Or am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIR, the `state` (according to the TF nomenclature) is a tuple of vectors representing the inner state (indeed) of the cell and which is passed through the timesteps, while the question is focusing on the final output of the cell. By the way, the state size is not said to be the same of the output.

Comment: If only official documentation included such examples to demonstrate the behavior

Comment: @pertux I think LSTM has a tuple output for last state, which contains the last state and the output, so you can index for the output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what [gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) is for!

```
def extract_axis_1(data, ind):
    """
    Get specified elements along the first axis of tensor.
    :param data: Tensorflow tensor that will be subsetted.
    :param ind: Indices to take (one for each element along axis 0 of data).
    :return: Subsetted tensor.
    """

    batch_range = tf.range(tf.shape(data)[0])
    indices = tf.stack([batch_range, ind], axis=1)
    res = tf.gather_nd(data, indices)

    return res
```

In your case:

```
output = extract_axis_1(output, lengths - 1)
```

Now `output` is a tensor of dimension `[batch_size, num_cells]`.

Comment: Great! I tried to edit the answer and add all the code so that it was self-contained, but I had a weird message saying that `the edit queue is full`. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 9):

From the following two sources,

http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/

```
outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
cell=cell,
dtype=tf.float64,
sequence_length=X_lengths,
inputs=X)
```

Or https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/14_recurrent_neural_networks.ipynb,

It is clear the last_states can be directly extracted from the SECOND output of the dynamic_rnn call. It will give you the last_states across **all** layers (in LSTM it is compsed from LSTMStateTuple) , while the outputs contains all the states in the **last** layer.

Comment: god i too get annoyed to no end by tensorflow documentation

Comment: If you are using a dropout it will be applied to FIRST OUTPUT but not the SECOND OUTPUT  of the dynamic_rnn return. please see [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/EhZ6uWxpFzc)

Answer (score 5):

Okay — so, looks like there actually **is** an easier solution. As @Shao Tang and @Rahul mentioned, the preferred way to do this would be by accessing the final cell state. Here’s why:

- If you look at the GRUCell source code (below), you’ll see that the “state” that the cell maintains is actually the hidden weights themselves. So, when the `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` returns the final state, it is actually returning the final hidden weights that you are interested in. To prove this, I just tweaked your setup and got the results:

GRUCell Call (rnn_cell_impl.py):

```
def call(self, inputs, state):
"""Gated recurrent unit (GRU) with nunits cells."""
if self._gate_linear is None:
      bias_ones = self._bias_initializer
if self._bias_initializer is None:
        bias_ones = init_ops.constant_initializer(1.0, dtype=inputs.dtype)
with vs.variable_scope("gates"):  # Reset gate and update gate.
self._gate_linear = _Linear(
            [inputs, state],
2 * self._num_units,
True,
bias_initializer=bias_ones,
kernel_initializer=self._kernel_initializer)
    value = math_ops.sigmoid(self._gate_linear([inputs, state]))
    r, u = array_ops.split(value=value, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    r_state = r * state
if self._candidate_linear is None:
with vs.variable_scope("candidate"):
self._candidate_linear = _Linear(
            [inputs, r_state],
self._num_units,
True,
bias_initializer=self._bias_initializer,
kernel_initializer=self._kernel_initializer)
    c = self._activation(self._candidate_linear([inputs, r_state]))
    new_h = u * state + (1 - u) * c
return new_h, new_h
```

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)

inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                    [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                    dtype=np.int32)
lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_, state_ = sess.run([output, state], {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print (output_)
    print (state_)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [-0.24305521 -0.15512943  0.06614969  0.16873555]
  [-0.62767833 -0.30741733  0.14819752  0.44313088]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

 [[-0.99152333 -0.1006391   0.28767768  0.76360202]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]
[[-0.62767833 -0.30741733  0.14819752  0.44313088]
 [-0.99152333 -0.1006391   0.28767768  0.76360202]]
```

- For other readers who are working with the LSTMCell (another popular option), things work a little differently. The LSTMCell maintains the state in a different way - cell state is either a tuple or a concatenated version of the actual cell state and the hidden state. So, to access the final hidden weights, you could set (`is_state_tuple` to `True`) during cell-initialization, and the final state will be a tuple : (final cell state, final hidden weights). So, in this case,

  _, (_, h) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)

will give you the final weights.

References: 
[c_state and m_state in Tensorflow LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789133/c-state-and-m-state-in-tensorflow-lstm)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/438604fc885208ee05f9eef2d0f2c630e1360a83/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L308
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/438604fc885208ee05f9eef2d0f2c630e1360a83/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L415

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the solution was not that hard. I implemented the following code:

```
slices = []
for index, l in enumerate(tf.unstack(lengths)):
    slice = tf.slice(rnn_out, begin=[index, l - 1, 0], size=[1, 1, 3])
    slices.append(slice)
last = tf.concat(0, slices)
```

So, the full snippet would be the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch = 2
dim = 3
hidden = 4

lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch])
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[batch, None, dim])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden)
cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch, tf.float32)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, lengths, initial_state=cell_state)

inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
                    [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]],
                    dtype=np.int32)
lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1], dtype=np.int32)

slices = []
for index, l in enumerate(tf.unstack(lengths)):
    slice = tf.slice(output, begin=[index, l - 1, 0], size=[1, 1, 3])
    slices.append(slice)
last = tf.concat(0, slices)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    outputs = sess.run([output, last], {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})
    print 'RNN output:'
    print(outputs[0])
    print
    print 'last relevant output:'
    print(outputs[1])
```

And the output:

```
RNN output:
[[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-0.06667092 -0.09284072  0.01098599 -0.03676109]
 [-0.09101103 -0.19828682  0.03546784 -0.08721405]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

[[-0.00025157 -0.05704876  0.05527233 -0.03741353]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]]

last relevant output:
[[[-0.09101103 -0.19828682  0.03546784]]

 [[-0.00025157 -0.05704876  0.05527233]]]
```

Comment: I would change tf.unpack() with tf.unstacks() as tf.unpack is deprecated:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#unpack

Comment: you could also avoid the for loop using ```tf.gather``` as it is commented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow and it is adapted for this same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267829/retrieving-last-value-of-lstm-sequence-in-tensorflow/41273843#41273843

Comment: @pabaldonedo I tried a solution with the `tf.gather` function but I have a warning saying that `Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.` I googled around a found that this can be originated by the `tf.gather`. Switching back to my solution, solves the problem. Any hint?

Comment: That is probably because tf.gather does not know in advance the size of the tensor. For example, if the input tensor has shape [None, 10], that None (dimension to be set dynamically when executing the graph) will lead tf.gather to that warning. If you have a fixed batch_size of let's say 5 and substitute input tensor to [5, 10] I think the warning will disappear.

Comment: Maybe the last dimension of the `size` argument of `tf.slice` should be `hidden`, i.e., 4?