# How to use LSTM stepwise - i.e. with new state - without changing parts of the graph following the LSTM-Cell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

In a Reinforcement Learning setting i want to use a LSTM. Due to this i have to compute single LSTM-steps (timesteps). 
Now this would typically look roughly like this:

```
inputx = tf.placeholder()
lstm_cell = tf.nn.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hiddenunits)
state = lstm_cell.zero_state
for i in range(timesteps):
    lstm_out, state = lstm_cell(inputx, state)
    out = sess.run(lstm_out, feed_dict={inputx:my_input})
    my_input = my_environment.step(out) # returns the observation
```

Normally updating state in this style works perfectly well, because everything, which is dependent on state (i.e. lstm_out) is also redefined. But consider a case, where some more complex stuff should happen with the output of a lstm:

```
output1 = tf.someoperation1(out)
output2 = tf.someoperation2(out)
output3 = tf.someoperation3(out)
```

If i want to have output1, output2 and output3 in each iteration, to my knowledge i have to tell tensorflow again in each iteration how to compute them:

```
inputx = tf.placeholder()
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hiddenunits)
    state = lstm_cell.zero_state
    for i in range(timesteps):
        lstm_out, state = lstm_cell(inputx, state)
        output1 = tf.someoperation1(out)
        output2 = tf.someoperation2(out)
        output3 = tf.someoperation3(out)
        out1, out2, out3 = session.run([output1, output2, output3], feed_dict={inputx:my_input})
        my_input = my_environment.step(out1, out2, out3) # returns the observation
```

This seems not only inconvenient to me, but i also assume it floods my tensorflow graph with lots of nodes from the same operation, which is kind of unnecessary. Is there any nice solution to this?

I already see, how bundling output1, output2 and output3 in a function would at least improve convenience and readability:

```
def some_function(lstm_output):
    output1 = tf.someoperation1(lstm_output)
    output2 = tf.someoperation2(lstm_output)
    output3 = tf.someoperation3(lstm_output)
    return output1, output2, output3

inputx = tf.placeholder()
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hiddenunits)
    state = lstm_cell.zero_state
    for i in range(timesteps):
        lstm_out, state = lstm_cell(inputx, state)
        out1, out2, out3 = some_function(lstm_out)
        out1, out2, out3 = session.run([output1, output2, output3], feed_dict={inputx:my_input})
        my_input = my_environment.step(out1, out2, out3) # returns the observation
```

But this is still kind of inconvenient, if you want to use the model on multiple instances, and i suppose it also just creates more and more trash in my graph? It seems to me like there might be some more convenient way to get this done, where one does not have to redefine everything after the changed state for tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your operations before the loop with placeholders and then only update the placeholder values with the `feed_dict` in `session.run()`.

Example (untested):

```
def some_function(lstm_output):
    output1 = tf.someoperation1(lstm_output)
    output2 = tf.someoperation2(lstm_output)
    output3 = tf.someoperation3(lstm_output)
    return output1, output2, output3

inputx = tf.placeholder()
state_ph = tf.placeholder(...) # fill in correct type an dimension
lstm_cell = tf.nn.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hiddenunits)
zero_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size=10, dtype=tf.float32)
state_val = session.run(zero_state)
lstm_out, state = lstm_cell(inputx, state_ph)
out1, out2, out3 = some_function(lstm_out)
for i in range(timesteps):
    out1_val, out2_val, out3_val, state_val = session.run([out1, out2, out3, state], feed_dict={inputx: my_input, state_ph: state_val})
```

This way, you only define your operations once and pass the updated values in each iteration to the placeholders.

### Edit

As it was rightfully pointed out, `state` is not a single tensor but a `LSTMStateTuple`. See also [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789133/what-are-c-state-and-m-state-in-tensorflow-lstm) for a good explanation of the LSTM state. Hence, we have to adapt the code slightly:

```
inputx = tf.placeholder(...) # define size and type
lstm_cell = tf.nn.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hiddenunits)
zero_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size=10, dtype=tf.float32)
c_state_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=zero_state.c.shape) 
h_state_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=zero_state.h.shape) 
cell_state_ph = LSTMStateTuple(c_state_ph, h_state_ph)
state_val = session.run(zero_state)
c_state_val = state_val.c
h_state_val = state_val.h
lstm_out, state = lstm_cell(inputx, cell_state_ph)
out1, out2, out3 = some_function(lstm_out)
for i in range(timesteps):
    out1_val, out2_val, out3_val, state_val = session.run([out1, out2, out3, state], feed_dict={inputx: my_input, c_state_ph: c_state_val, h_state_ph: h_state_val})
    c_state_val=state_val.c
    h_state_val=state_val.h
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this idea! I actually thought of that, to be honest i have not tried it until now, as the state typically is not a mere tensor, but rather a specific object (LSTMStateTuple (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMStateTuple)). Can a placeholder be used for such an object? I suppose i could set state_is_tuple = False, then it should work, but as of (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) this is deprecated.

Comment: I think you are right. If the state object returned by lstm_cell(inputx, state_ph) is a tuple and not a single tensor, then we have to do some extra work. We could extract the individual tensors from the tuple and create placeholder for each of these tensors. See my edit.

Comment: I am glad to hear that!