# Initializing LSTM hidden state in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Can someone tell me, in the TensorFlow framework, how to initialize the hidden states of a LSTM network with user-defined values? I am trying to incorporate side information to the LSTM by giving a specific hidden state of the first LSTM cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the initial hidden state of the LSTM by a parameter `initial_state` of the function responsible to unroll the graph.

I am assuming that you will use some of the following functions in tensorflow to create the Recurrent Neural Network (RNN): [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), [bidirectional_dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn), [tf.nn.static_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn), or [tf.nn.static_bidirectional_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_bidirectional_rnn) .
All of them have a `initial_state` parameter. In the case of a Bidirectional RNN, you need to pass the initial states for both forward (`initial_state_fw`) and backward (`initial_state_bw`) passes.

Example that defines a model with `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 32
max_sequence_length = 100
num_features = 128
num_units = 64 

input_sequence = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, max_sequence_length, num_features])
input_sequence_lengths = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=num_units, state_is_tuple=True)

# Initial states
cell_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, num_units], tf.float32)
hidden_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_units])
my_initial_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(cell_state, hidden_state)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                    cell=cell,
                    inputs=input_sequence,
                    initial_state=my_initial_state,
                    sequence_length=input_sequence_lengths)
```

Since we use `state_is_tuple=True`, we need to pass an initial state that is a tuple of the `cell_state` and the `hidden_state`. 
In the documentation of [LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell) this tuple corresponds to `c_state` and `m_state`, which [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360236/10530728) points out that this represents the cell state and hidden state, respectively.

Therefore, since we only want to initialize the first hidden state, the `cell_state` is initialized with zeros.