# How tf.nn.dynamic_rnn works with different lengths of inputs sepcially when working with seq2seq?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Here I am asking how the dynamic behavior work. 
This is the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) for above dynamic_rnn function. What is the maximum length of RNN input blocks that this function create? Will it pad all shorter ones according to the largest input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last output of a dynamic\_rnn in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-the-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is your responsibility to pad the sequences, and then supply the sequences lengths.

For example:

```
# Create input data
X = np.random.randn(2, 10, 8)

# The second example is of length 6 
X[1,6:] = 0
X_lengths = [10, 6]

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    dtype=tf.float64,
    sequence_length=X_lengths,
    inputs=X)
```

Here you can see, we pad the sequences ourselves  `X[1,6:] = 0` will assign 0 to all of the values after the 6th element, that means this sequence is of length 6 and we state so by giving `X_lengths` 2nd value the value 6

Comment: So what if we don't pad and feed the inputs? Will the dynamic RNN will pad all others sequences equal to longest seq?

Comment: You can't do that, dynamic_rnn expects a tensor, which has a fixed shape.
Tensors cannot have different lengths withing them, meaning the size has to be [batch_size, max_sequence_length, element_dim] 

So what you would do, is pad all the shorter ones to max_sequence_length yourself, there is a helper function for that in Keras, called pad_sequence

Comment: But this is what the document says

Unlike rnn, the input inputs is not a Python list of Tensors, one for each frame. Instead, inputs may be a single Tensor where the maximum time is either the first or second dimension (see the parameter time_major). Alternatively, it may be a (possibly nested) tuple of Tensors,

so we can input inputs with different seq2seq lengths without padding. But we have to input the max time as a tensor.

Comment: I don't see how that contradicts. The input is a tensor, usually if lets say we are using word2vec embeddings, it will be [batch_size, seq_length, embedding_dim].
Having each sequence in the same length is a must, since its a tensor - so lets say you already padded with zeros.
Now if you don't supply sequence length, what will happen is that the zeros will also be digested by the rnn, to avoid that, you supply sequence length and that way the dynamic_rnn knows when to stop feeding the cell

Comment: yes. So to have a maz se_length all should be padded to this. :)

Comment: Well there should be a difference between dynamic_rnn and static rnn. So I think in dynamic RNN we can input batches with different size of sequences. Otherwise what is the difference?

Comment: the difference is that when.you.supply.the sequence length like i showed in the example, it will only feed the lstm.cell with the length you supplied ignoring whatever goes after

Comment: so here dynamic_RNN function can create RNNs length of their actual units without zeros padded up?

Comment: you have to pad with zeros - so the tensor holding the sequences will be of a fixed size.

Comment: also you have to give the sequence lengths so the dynamic rnn will not process the zeros

Comment: so is it like bucketing right? Here with dynmic RNN we can train fast and without long useless padding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146166/discussion-between-shamane-siriwardhana-and-bluesummers).