# Hidden states vs. final state returned by Tensorflow's dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

[`tensorflow.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) creates a recurrent neural network given `cell`, which is an instance of `RNNCell`, and returns a pair consisting of:

- `outputs`: The RNN output Tensor
- `state`: The final state

Here is a toy recurrent neural network as well as its output[*]:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dim = 3
hidden = 4

lengths = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, None, dim])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
output, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
          cell, inputs, lengths, dtype=tf.float32)

inputs_ = np.asarray([[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
                     [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]],
                     [[9,9,9], [10,10,10], [11,11,11]]],                                          
                     dtype=np.int32)

lengths_ = np.asarray([3, 1, 2], dtype=np.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_, final_state_ = sess.run(
        [output, final_state],
        {inputs: inputs_, lengths: lengths_})

    print('hidden states:')
    print(output_)

    print('final state :')
    print(final_state_)
```

Output:

```
hidden states:
[[[ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
  [-3.0096283e-02  1.6747195e-01  2.3113856e-02 -4.5677904e-02]
  [-6.0795926e-02  3.5036778e-01  6.0140129e-02 -1.6039203e-01]]

 [[-2.1957003e-03  8.1749000e-02  1.2620161e-02 -2.8342882e-01]
  [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
  [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]]

 [[-1.7376180e-04  2.7789388e-02  3.1011081e-03 -3.5858861e-01]
  [-2.5059914e-04  4.5771234e-02  4.5708413e-03 -6.5035087e-01]
  [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]]]

final state :
LSTMStateTuple(
       c=array([[-1.0705842e-01,  5.2945197e-01,  1.5602852e-01, -2.5641304e-01],
       [-3.3140955e-03,  8.6112522e-02,  7.2794281e-02, -3.6088336e-01],
       [-3.4701003e-04,  4.6147645e-02,  6.7321308e-02, -8.6465287e-01]],
      dtype=float32),
       h=array([[-6.0795926e-02,  3.5036778e-01,  6.0140129e-02, -1.6039203e-01],
       [-2.1957003e-03,  8.1749000e-02,  1.2620161e-02, -2.8342882e-01],
       [-2.5059914e-04,  4.5771234e-02,  4.5708413e-03, -6.5035087e-01]],
      dtype=float32))
```

My understanding is as follows:

- Hidden states correspond to the output of LSTM cell at each timestep for each sequence in the batch;
- Final state encompasses last cell states for each sequence (`c` component) as well as last hidden states for each sequence (`h` component);

thus, am I not supposed to get the same values in `h` component of the finale state and in the last hidden state of each sequence?

[*] Code largely inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-the-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `h` of the final state component contains the **last output** of your LSTM, and **in the case of the dynamic_rnn it takes into account the length** that you give as parameter (`lengths`)

As you can see in your example `final_state.h[0]` is equal to `output[0][2]` , because the length of the first example is 3 , `final_state.h[1]` is equal to `output[1][0]` because the length of your second example is one etc..