# Tensorflow: Using one tensor to index slices of another

Tags: tensorflow

As motivation for this question, I'm trying to use variable length sequences with `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. When I was training with `batch_size=1` (one element at a time), everything was going swimmingly, but now I'm trying to increase the batch size, which means zero-padding sequences to the same length.

I've zero-padded (or truncated) all of my sequences up to the max length of 15000.

`outputs` (from the RNN) has shape `[batch_size, max_seq_length, num_units]`, which for concreteness is right now `[16, 15000, 64]`.

I also create a `seq_lengths` tensor, which is `[batch_size]`, so `[16]`, corresponding to the actual sequence length of all the zero-padded sequences.

I've added a fully connected layer, to multiply what was previously `outputs[:,-1,:]` by W, then add a bias term, since ultimately I'm just trying to predict a single value (or rather `batch_size` values). However, now, I can't just naively use -1 as the index, because all of the sequences have been variously padded! I have `seq_lengths`, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it to index `outputs`. I've searched around, and I think the answer is some clever use of `tf.gather_nd`, but I can't quite figure it out. I can easily see how to take individual values, but I want to preserve entire slices. Do I need to create some sort of enormous 3D mask?

Here's what I want in terms of a Python comprehension (outputs is an `np.array`): `outputs = np.array([outputs[i, seq_lengths[i], :] for i in range(batch_size)])`.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex. To be explicit, I want to translate the line at the bottom ( `outputs = ...`) into Tensorflow, where `outputs` is a `[batch_size, max_seq_length, num_units]` Tensor, and `seq_lengths` is a `[batch_size]` Tensor. What I want is for `seq_lengths` to "pick out" or "slice" `outputs` with just the correct middle dimension value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Alex it turns out you've already answered my question for me :).

After some more research, I came across the following, which is exactly my use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298689/5526865 . I won't copy the code here, but just check that out.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Will mark this question as a duplicate.